# Rails 4 - Active Job: Run Job Only When User Is Signed In

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, resque, rails-activejob

I'm currently using Active Job/Resque to pull from an external api. It works perfectly but I want it to periodically pull from the api (and update Records) while the user is signed in.

Devise provides the current_user method which I cannot seem to use and I can't seem to check the session to break the loop. If I put the logic in the controller then it impacts page loads, etc. which defeats the purpose.

Basically, this is what I want to do:

```
class PullApiJob < ActiveJob::Base
  queue_as :default

  def perform(current_user, info)
    while current_user
      #Logic to pull info from api and save into Info record
      sleep(200) 
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: As far as I knw, `current_user` is something which is available in controllers only. You should enqueue the job with user id and then create user object in the job and do whatever you want.

Comment: You are correct in that current_user is only available to the controller. That is the root of the problem. Checking current_user and polling the user session isn't possible in active job from my testing so I'm at a loss as to performing the job incrementally only when the user is signed in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about check session time every request and store in db.  add `session_timeout_at`

**for every request,**

```
if current_user && DateTime.now > current_user.session_timeout_at
  current_user.update(session_timeout_at: DateTime.now + session_duration)
  # session_duration => session expire duration, ex) 30.minutes
end
```

**Your job**

```
class PullApiJob < ActiveJob::Base
  queue_as :default

  def perform(current_user, info)
    while current_user.session_timeout_at > DateTime.now do
      # Your Logic
      sleep(200)
      current_user.reload # <- Must reload for check updated session_timeout_at
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: I'm going to try a modified version of this. As written, it would expire sessions for active users. Devise currently provides :timeoutable so I'm going to try to work around that using the same concept.